# Array com dados do banco de dados

Tags: php

Preciso montar um array puxando os slug da minha tabela, exemplo:

```
$array = array (
  'esportes',
  'mundo',
  'estado'
);
```

Tentei assim:

```
$slug = $con->prepare("SELECT slug FROM categorias");
$slug->execute();
$array = array (
   foreach ( $slug as $row ) {
      echo "'.$row['slug'].',";
   }
);
```

Preciso usar esse array pra fazer uma url amigável que ta assim:

```
$url = $_GET['url'];
$sep = array_filter ( explode ( "/", $url ) );
```

Aqui preciso do array:

```
if ( isset ( $sep[0] ) && $sep[0] in_array ( $sep[0], $array ) ) {
   $Categoria = new Categoria;
   $Categoria->GetCategoria;
}
```

Alguém sabe alguma solução?

Comment: Se você usa PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/pdostatement.fetchall.php; senão, https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Comment: @Valdeir Par usando a primeira opção eu posso fazer aquele 'if?

Comment: O seu último `if..isset`? Depende da sua estrutura de dados e do retorno dos dados.

Comment: @Valdeir Par o retorno seria o array

Answer (score -1):

Na sua consulta tente assim:

`$slug = $con->prepare("SELECT slug FROM categorias");
 $slug->execute();
 $array = array ();
   foreach ( $slug->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $row ) {
      $array[] = $row['slug'];
   }`